# how to make a div content responsive?

Tags: css

I m trying to practice the responsive design. What i want to do is a div inside of a div a span and a button. button is totally right and span is totally left. When i try to resize the window,button and span should come closer because of the divs size.
So far what i did is :

```
<div style="background-color: white; width: 50%; height: 50px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 0.5px"><span>My Word</span>
     <button style="height: 50px; width: 50px; position absolute; margin-left: 268px"></button></div>
```

it doesnt quite working..
And ideas how to archieve this ?

Comment: Use relative position and relative margin for your button, like `<button style="height: 50px; width: 50px; position: relative; margin-left: 25%"></button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove `position absolute;` on the botton and replace it with `float: right"`, then add `position: relative` on the div to content the botton and the span.

```html
<div style="background-color: white; width: 50%; height: 50px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 0.5px; position: relative">
  <span>My Word</span>
  <button style="height: 50px; width: 50px; float: right">button</button>
</div>
```

and since you want to learn responsive design i think you shall visit

[Responsive web design basics | Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/?hl=en)

[Responsive Web Design: What It Is and How To Use It](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

and avoid inline styling

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would advise against using in-line styling, always make an external style sheet.

There are a lot of ways you can make responsive designs, media queries is one example.

You can read more on it here:

[How to make a DIV element responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151213/how-to-make-a-div-element-responsive)

```
 @media screen and (min-width:761px){
        body{
        background-color:white;
    }
     h1{
        color:red;
    }    
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:760px){
           body{ background-color: #333;
        }
     h1{
        color:red;
    }  
    p{
        color: white;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:480px){
           body{ background-color: #807f83;
        }
     h1{
        color:white;
    }  
    p{
        color: white;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:360px){
           body{ background-color: #0096d6;
        }
     h1{
        color:white;
        font-size:25px;
    }  
    p{
        color: white;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`float` should fix your problem.

add `float: right;`to your button and remove the `margin`.

```
<button style="height: 50px; width: 50px; position absolute; float: right;"></button>
```